# Como usar el SELECT FROM con 2 condiciones

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo una tabla en la  que quiero que se muestre solo las solicitudes pendientes y resueltas del campo estado de mi tabla en mi BD.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM contribuyente WHERE estado ='Pendiente' AND 
  estado='Resuelto' ORDER BY id
```

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de dato es la columna `estado` en tu tabla? Un `SHOW CREATE TABLE contribuyente;` te lo dirá con exactitud y sería información muy útil para poder ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como las condicionales esta en el mismo campo, tiene que utilizar la propiedad where in , que me permita consulta varias condiciones en un campo

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM contribuyente
         WHERE estado in ('Pendiente','Resuelto')  ORDER BY id
```